# What are the possible ways to play audio from octave on a Mac?

Tags: macos, audio, octave

playaudio() dies because there's no /dev/dsp.

None of the outputs from saveaudio() in various formats seem to be playable in QuickTime or VLC.

Ideal of course would be something like playaudio(), saving a file and playing it is a work-around that's hideously sub-optimal, but better than nothing.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1478071/how-do-i-play-a-sound-in-octave/2047555#2047555 for a possible workaround.

Comment: Thanks, though I couldn't get that working.  The best solution I've found was to run Linux in a virtual machine.  :-/

Answer (score 1):

So, this question is ultra old, but since I just had to solve it and could not find any direct answers on the web, thought I would write something here:

First install SoX: http://sox.sourceforge.net/

Now on the terminal command line you can use:

```
play “sound file.wav"
```

...and you will hear beautiful music.

But that command does not work from within Octave. This does work:

```
system(‘play “sound file.wav”’);
```