# Play sound in octave with pulseaudio

Tags: linux, audio, signal-processing, octave, pulseaudio

I would like to play sound in octave with `pulseaudio`. I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1478071/how-do-i-play-a-sound-in-octave) post but the `octave` audio management is changed in the new releases and it is not longer possible to use `paplay` like say that post, I have the version `4.2.1-4`

Now when I try to use `sound` or `audiolayer` functions I get these errors:

```
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1052:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
ALSA lib pcm.c:2495:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.rear
ALSA lib pcm.c:2495:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.center_lfe
ALSA lib pcm.c:2495:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.side
ALSA lib pcm_route.c:867:(find_matching_chmap) Found no matching channel map
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1052:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1052:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
connect(2) call to /dev/shm/jack-1000/default/jack_0 failed (err=No such file or directory)
attempt to connect to server failed
```

And no sound is played, next, if I retry to use `sound` I don't get error and it waits for the sound duration, however it keep to not play sound.

It seems it would like to use `ALSA`, but I'm using `pulseaudio` what can i do?

EDIT:

I notice that sometimes the error message change and it say:

```
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1052:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
Expression 'ret' failed in 'src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c', line: 1735
Expression 'AlsaOpen( &alsaApi->baseHostApiRep, params, streamDir, &self->pcm )' failed in 'src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c', line: 1902
Expression 'PaAlsaStreamComponent_Initialize( &self->playback, alsaApi, outParams, StreamDirection_Out, NULL != callback )' failed in 'src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c', line: 2170
Expression 'PaAlsaStream_Initialize( stream, alsaHostApi, inputParameters, outputParameters, sampleRate, framesPerBuffer, callback, streamFlags, userData )' failed in 'src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c', line: 2835
error: audioplayer: unable to open audio playback stream
error: called from
    playblocking at line 36 column 3
    sound at line 59 column 3
```

Comment: do you have `jack` installed by any chance?